# How to render different ejs files for different browser sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I am using node js to to create the server. I want to render mobile.ejs if screen size is shorter beyond some point or else I want to render dashboard.ejs.

This is what I tried

```
if($(window).width()>414){
        res.render("dashboard");
      }
      else{
        res.render("mobile");
      }
```

I have required jquery using npm in app.js file but the argument $(window).width() is returning 0 instead of the size of the browser.
Please tell where did I go wrong or suggest a better solution

Comment: The window doesn't exist on the server, and the size might change after the server has rendered the page anyway. Look at using CSS media queries instead.

Comment: The 2 ejs files have different html in them, so It is not only styling that I have to change I wish to change the complete page. So i cannot use CSS media queries i guess

Comment: Providing completely different pages for the same URL is generally not a good idea.

Comment: but is it possible to render different pages for the same url. If yes, then how?

Comment: See the duplicate